# ArcObjects - IExportPDF2 and esriExportPDFLayerOptions Not Working as Expected

Tags: arcobjects, pdf

I have a small function that exports a map document to a pdf.  The function works in the fact that it does export a pdf.  However, regardless of what I set *pdfExport.ExportPDFLayersAndFeatureAttributes* to, all of the layers are grouped into a single layer 'Image' in the output pdf.  In the code snippet below, I would expect the map layers to be toggle-able layers in the output pdf.  What am I doing wrong?

BTW - this is at ArcGIS 9.3.1

```c#
int OUTPUT_RES = 300;
IExport export = null;

IExportPDF2 pdfExport = new ExportPDFClass();
pdfExport.ExportPDFLayersAndFeatureAttributes = esriExportPDFLayerOptions.esriExportPDFLayerOptionsLayersAndFeatureAttributes;

export = (IExport)pdfExport;
export.Resolution = OUTPUT_RES;
export.ExportFileName = outputFile;

tagRECT exportFrame = map.ActiveView.ExportFrame;
IEnvelope exportEnvelope = new EnvelopeClass();
exportEnvelope.PutCoords(exportFrame.left, exportFrame.top, exportFrame.right, exportFrame.bottom);
export.PixelBounds = exportEnvelope;

int hdc = export.StartExporting();
map.ActiveView.Output(hdc, OUTPUT_RES,exportFrame,null,null);
export.FinishExporting();
export.Cleanup();
```

Comment: If i remember correctly the layers may need to be grouped, then each group becomes a layer in the PDF.  Or something like that. Also, if you have a raster layer in there, every layer bellow the raster will be rasterized. Transparencies also don't play well with the PDF renderer - might need to turn those off as well.

Comment: Perhaps I should have first asked if you've tried this using the default PDF exporter and whether that yielded the expected result...

Comment: Can you get the results you want interactively using the export command in arcmap?

Comment: Exporting manually from ArcMap produces expected result; pdf with same layer groupings as in map document.